# jQtransform Checkbox Click Problem on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox

There is a very strange problem with jQTransform and jQery 1.4.2.

When I use the jQTransform plugin on any form my checkboxes stop working appropriately.

This is the behavior:

- The first click on a checkbox, marks it
- From that point on i need to click it twice to unmark / mark it

I did a some Google search before creating this question and I found [this jQuery Forum Question/Answer](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqtransform-checkbox-click-problem-with-ie)

The solution won't work for me because turning to lower versions of jQuery is not an option.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem using jQtransform and jQuery 1.4.2 ???

I can't figure what changed between versions to make this new "behavior" on 
jQuery 1.4.2

**IMPORTANT:** This only happens in IE. As usual Firefox is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is bugs all over the place. I worked around it like this in the clickhandler for checkbox - if you put an alert above teh change trigger you see it doesnt change - so just check that if I didnt change you do it manually... quick and dirty but worked

```
//make my own checkpointvariable
              firstONE=inputSelf.checked;    


  //only original row
$input.trigger('click').trigger("change");
//second line of checking
 secondOne = inputSelf.checked;
 if(firstONE==secondOne)
  inputSelf.click();
 //for some strange reason - when it doesnt change i change it  instead...
```

thats all it took...

Answer (score 2):

I have find a "solution" to this problem, not really clean but it work at least with ie7/8 ...
just copy/paste the following block "$input.change(function(){..." with this one :

```
var ieStep=1;    
$input.change(function(){
    if($.browser.msie){
    if((ieStep%2) == 1){$input.trigger("click"); checkStep = 1;} else {ieStep++;}
    }
```

and the "aLink.click(function(){..." with this :

```
aLink.click(function(){
//do nothing if the original input is disabled
if($input.attr('disabled')){return false;}

//trigger the envents on the input object
    if($.browser.msie){
    if((ieStep%2) == 0){$input.trigger("click"); checkStep=0;}  
        $input.trigger("change");   
    }
    else {
                $input.trigger("click").trigger("change");  
            }
    ieStep++;
return false;
});
```

that's all

Fabien

Answer (score 0):

i've fixed that, the problems was actually because there is one click by a browser and other by a library

so there is new library I’ve created – csTransPie – basing it on jqtransform – jqtransform is a great library but it really has many problems, today css3 solves many of those problems and I like the idea of controls being normal controls and looking the same in every browser
https://github.com/pkoretic/csTransPie

It’s a work in progress but even now it’s better than jqtransform (more than half of the css rewritten, many bugs solved, clean css…)

now you can use it per element with just one class!

all suggestions are welcome!